# Are the network interface card same in all cisco devices

Tags: router, routing, network-adapter

I have old cisco 2600 routers but they dont have any `network interface card`

My friend has cisco pix firewall which has network card attached with `4 ports`

so can i pull the network card from `cisco pix 525` and put in cisco 2600 router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through specifications for both products, and it appears that the PIX  interface cards have different part numbers.

However, if you note that the card slot dimensions are identical, and you're careful not to force an incompatible card in and damage internal connectors, it may work.